# Get Battery Standby time, 2G/3G Usage in Android

Tags: android

I would like to get the following information from my Android device programmatically:

- How much battery is being used by each component of my Android device.
- The battery stand by time of my Android device.
- The 2G and 3G usage of my Android device.

How could I go about implementing this using available Android API's?

Thank You

Comment: Did you find the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

For data usage stats, please check:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html
http://agolovatyuk.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-traffic-statistics-inside.html
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtuning/tree/master/TrafficMonitor

Regarding battery:
One option would be to subscribe for battery status updates
http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-sdk-get-device-battery-information/
http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html
http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/docking-monitoring.html

and then display time since unplugged. However, this will reset the time if you connect device to power supply for a minute. So you may be more interested in displaying device uptime or sum of all discharging times since device was turned on.

Comment: This answer is just a bunch of links and not a solution.  Please make it an actual answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

> battery standby time

There is no way to obtain a value for this. You are welcome to examine the battery charge (via `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` and the extras defined on `BatteryManager`) and come up with your own estimation.

> 2G usage and 3G usage

There is no way to obtain a value for these. `TrafficStats` and its `getMobile...()` methods will allow you to measure bandwidth consumed over mobile data, but it does not differentiate between types of mobile data, and it does not include time spent on telephony operations like SMS and phone calls.

Answer (score 0):

for battery stats use this library it act as proxy for the hidden api to obtain battery stats and if phone is kitkat and above you need root access as the google have moved the service which use to provide battery stats as system app

https://github.com/asksven/AndroidCommon

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please improve it by adding details (such as example code).

Answer (score 0):

For battery remaining stat use 
`BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY` Remaining battery capacity as an integer percentage of total capacity (with no fractional part).
`BATTERY_PROPERTY_CHARGE_COUNTER` gives Battery capacity in microampere-hours, as an integer.

```
BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_AVERAGE gives  Average battery current in microamperes, as an integer.

BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW  gives Instantaneous battery current in microamperes, as an integer.
```

`BATTERY_PROPERTY_ENERGY_COUNTER` gives Battery remaining energy in nanowatt-hours, as a long integer.

Refer BatteryManager developer page

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html
```

FOR 2G or 3G detection you can use DATA_ACTIVITY_IN from the telephontManager class to detect usage.
To determine whether your network is 2G or3G use:

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int networkType = mTelephonyManager.getNetworkType();
    switch (networkType) {
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN:
            return "2G";
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP:
            return "3G";
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE:
            return "4G";
        default:
            return "Unknown";
    }
}
```

Use DATA_ACTIVITY_IN in combination with this to get aprropriate useage.
 For more info refer

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html
```